# How to set dynamic styles in Vue.js component from Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set an array of components styles directly from the store, so that when the store changes, the design of each component changes too.

I store a set of links in my Vuex store like this:

```
links: [
    {id: 1, text: 'Banana is a test', design: {color: 'red', 'background-color': 'blue', padding: '51px', margin: '5px', 'border-width' : '10px', 'border-color': 'blue', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
    {id: 2, text: 'This is a test', design: {color: 'red', 'background-color': 'blue', padding: '20px', margin: '10px', 'border-width' : '10px', 'border-color': 'green', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
    {id: 3, text: 'Monkey is a test', design: {color: 'red', 'background-color': 'blue', padding: '5px', margin: '5px', 'border-width' : '10px', 'border-color': 'green', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
]
```

and this is how I try to render them

```
<a v-for="link in links" :key=link.id :href="link.destination" :id=link.id :style="link.design">
   {{link.text}}
</a>
```

the trouble is, when the design objects changes in the Vuex store, the links styles are not subsequently updated as I would expect.

In my Vue component I've tried getting the links in different ways, assuming this would change the reactivity. Currently I get them using a computed method like so:

```
computed: {
    getLinks: function() {
        return this.$store.state.links
    }
},
```

but whenever I change the value of a background-color, say from 'blue' to 'red', I have to reload the page to see the change. Do I need to force a rerender of the page everytime I call my mutation?

This is my mutation for reference:

```
setSelectedItemDesign (state, payload ) {
    state.selectedItem.design[Object.keys(payload)[0]] = Object.values(payload)[0]
}
```

and I'd call it from my component like this:

```
this.$store.commit('setSelectedItemDesign', {'background-color' : this.rgbaValue})
```

Comment: style name is written through camelCase, example: `fontSize`

Comment: I think this link may help you. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: @nada thanks you were right

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you read value from store directly here `return this.$store.state.links`. This way it is not reactive and also anitpattern, because you should not access store like that.

You should create getter to get value and then it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not updating the array in my store in a way that Vue observes to trigger a view update, as nada correctly pointed out.

You can see here for more details: vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection